# Given that $\int f d\mu$ and $\int g d\mu$ exist, $\int f d\mu+\int g d\mu$ is well-defined, to show existence of $\int \left(f +g\right) d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

**The Problem :** Given that, $\int f  d\mu$ and $\int g  d\mu$ exist and $\int f  d\mu+\int g  d\mu$ is well-defined, I have to show that $\int \left(f +g\right) d\mu$ exists. As I see it, I need to show that $f+g$ is Borel, i.e.
$$\left(f+g\right)^{-1}\left(B\right) \in \mathcal{F}, \text{ for all } B \in \mathcal{B}.$$

**My progress and where I'm stuck :** Let $B \in \mathcal{B}$.
Consider the set $\left(f+g\right)^{-1}\left(B\right)=\left\{\omega \in \Omega : f\left(\omega\right)+g\left(\omega\right) \in B\right\}$. Now, this set is equal to
$$\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left\{\omega \in \Omega : f\left(\omega\right)=x, g\left(\omega\right) \in B-x\right\},$$ where $B-x=\left\{b-x : b \in B\right\}$. I think that we can show that for fixed $x \in \mathbb{R},$ the set $\left\{\omega \in \Omega : f\left(\omega\right)=x, g\left(\omega\right) \in B-x\right\}$ is Borel. But we have an uncountable unionin our hand, while we needed a countable one! How do I proceed?

Comment: The way I see it is that you must show that at least one of the integrals $\int(f+g)_+d\mu$, $\int(f+g)_-d\mu$ is finite. Indeed, $f+g$ must be measurable and that can be shown on base of the fact that $f$ and $g$ are measurable. Do you want to see that proved as well?

Comment: It'd be great if you could supply the proof for measurability $f+g$. Once that is done, I guess I can handle the part of showing at least one of the non-negative Borel integrals is finite.

Comment: I think that the basic problem is that I'm not familiar with the powerful limit theorems yet. In the book it is asked to prove these properties using fundamental definitions only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operation $+:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x+y$ is continuous if $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R$ are both equipped with their usual topology.

That implies that the operation is measurable if $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R$ are both equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

The measurability of $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ implies that the function $h:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\langle f(x),g(y)\rangle$ is measurable.

Then composition $+\circ h$ prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto f(x)+g(y)$ is measurable.

Also read my comment, and check whether you have interpreted the question posed unto you correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: You are very welcome.